# Who abducted Addison in "Wit's End"?

Tags: karen-joy-fowler, wits-end

In Fowler's *Wit's End* (also published as *The Case of the Imaginary Detective*), we see a flashback where Addison is abducted at age three.

It's a strange scene. There are three people involved; she isn't mistreated; she's let out to play in the garden, and her parents find her there immediately. It seems... *weird*, for an abduction; I'm not seeing any of the motivation or the secrecy I'd expect from the abduction of a child.

Is any explanation given for the events in this scene? Are we meant to understand who took her, or why?